# Heptaphase electrical current

Tags: current

Taking into account the advantages of triphase current in relation to monophase current, I keep wondering if a multi-phase current such as heptaphase would be more advantageous than triphase. Does anybody know if this has been tried or proven?

Comment: Once upon in the time, but just because rectifying gave smoother DC voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the fewer conductors you have to route the better. Biphase requires 3 conductors, triphase also requires 3 conductors (when balanced), so triphase is used for preference.

Triphase is already enough achieve constant torque in motors and generators, so there seems to be little incentive to increase the number of phases.

DC bus rectifiers **do** use hexaphase, and even duodecaphase (12), as these are easy to make from the existing triphase supply, giving a steady DC supply from the rectifier.

Comment: Biphase requires 4 conductors, because they are shifted by 90 degrees. Stepper motor is two phase, but no one can use only 3 condutors.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys, it was something I wanted to do for my graduation project (demonstrate that an AC motor would be more efficient running on a heptaphase current rather than triphase) but I completely agree with you Neil, that the juice wouldn't be worth the squeeze, as triphase motors are already very efficient and the need for extra conductors wouldn't compensate...still would have been an interesting project though!